# Jump height being affected by the duration of how long jump button is pressed

Tags: xna, monogame, input

So I've been trying to implement a controlled jump the way the title proclaims to make the game easier to play and having the ability to make harder challenges in each level. I have noticed how there are already posts regarding this subject so I have read each individual post trying to implement it by myself. I do think I managed to come up with something good but it is not working properly (this script is placed inside the Players Update method):

```
timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;


        if ((InputManager.pad.IsButtonDown(Buttons.A) && InputManager.lastPad.IsButtonUp(Buttons.A) ||
            InputManager.keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && InputManager.lastKeys.IsKeyUp(Keys.Up)) ||
            (jumpTime < 0 && !isGrounded && !isJumping))
        {
            if (jumpTime < 0)
            {
                speed.Y = -jumpTime * speed.Y;
                jumpTime += timer;
            }

            else if (isGrounded)
            {
                speed.Y = -8.5f;
                jumpTime = 7.0f;
                speed.Y = jumpTime * speed.Y;
                isGrounded = false;
            }
            else if (!isJumping)
            {
                speed.Y = -8.5f;
                jumpTime = -6.0f;
                speed.Y = -jumpTime * speed.Y;
                isJumping = true;
            }

            else if (jumpTime > 0)
            {
                speed.Y = jumpTime * speed.Y;
                jumpTime -= timer;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            jumpTime = 0;
        }
```

Basically, the problem with it is the player jumps infinitely and never stops once the button is pressed. I would take a guess that the if-statement has some errors, but I could be wrong. Could I get some advice of what I've done wrong here exactly?

I want to mention too that it's going to be a double jump mechanic, where the double jump is also affected by the duration of how long the jump key is pressed.

Comment: Seen this? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45704/impulsioned-jumping

Comment: I strongly recommend you take a look at http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html -- It would help you clean up your player update and be able to reason about your jump code more clearly.

Comment: You may also find the talk ["Building a Better Jump" from the Math for Game Programmers track at this year's GDC](http://gdcvault.com/play/1023559/Math-for-Game-Programmers-Building) helpful.

Comment: Wanted to mention I got it to work some time ago. The downside could be the gravity isn't realistic but the effect I'm looking for is there. Thank you people :)