# Inconsistent jump height

Tags: physics, jumping

I am doing some physics for a platformer game in MonoGame. The jump height changes based on FPS even though I'm using delta time. When the FPS decreases and gravity is added before movement, the jump height is shorter than usual. How do I keep a consistent jump height at all frame rates?

Here's the pseudo-code executed each frame:

```
velocity.Y += gravity * dt;
Move(velocity * dt);
```

Comment: You move after you change the velocity, change the order of them

Comment: Then the jump height will be higher than usual when the framerate decreases.

Comment: https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/

Comment: @Bálint Why does OP have to change the order?

Comment: It doesn't matter how small dt is, the jump height will always be variable to some degree when dt varies with this technique and it will. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong because I've never seen a professional platformer where the character jumped higher/lower on different frame rates.

Comment: Although, I'd have to say I prefer jumping lower on low frame rates because jumping higher leaves an exploit to reach places you're not supposed to reach.

Comment: I think the answer is in the accepted answer to this question, but I can't quite see how it translates to my algorithm. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45704/impulsioned-jumping?rq=1

Comment: This is something called integration error. The [Euler integration method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) you're using is particularly susceptible to this, with error per step proportional to the square of the step size. So as your timestep varies, the result changes quite wildly. You can reduce the error by using more sophisticated integrators like RK4, but they'll always have some timestep sensitivity. Switching to a constant timestep as Bálint suggests will guarantee you get consistent results even if your integrator is simple.

Comment: How are you determining for how long to apply the jump? If dt is large you can overshoot your jump time if you apply full dt to applied velocity for jump. If dt is small it should be fine. What's your jump code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most commonly used method in commercial engines is the semi-implicit Euler method that I'm already using as you can see in my pseudo-code (https://gafferongames.com/post/integration_basics/). But this doesn't give 100% accurate jump height. Everyone tells me to implement RK4 and/or make dt as small as possible. Neither of these things is necessary. While it would be great if the game could run at a consistent 60 FPS on all machines it's just not realistic.

I figured out how to achieve a consistent jump height with no downsides. First of all, you add half of the gravity before and after you move with velocity. Secondly, you need to check if adding the gravity will make the object move in the opposite y direction if so you should first move to the position where velocity.Y = 0 and then add the gravity to the velocity, so the object will move that distance in the next frame.

So how do you find the position where velocity.Y = 0? By using physical formulas.

The time from now until the object's velocity = 0

t = velocity.Y / gravity

The y-distance from here until the position where velocity.Y = 0

y = -0.5 * gravity * t^2 + velocity.Y * t

So in pseudo-code:

```
if (velocity.Y < 0 && velocity.Y + (gravity * dt) >= 0)
{
    float t = velocity.Y / gravity;
    float y = (-0.5f * gravity * (t * t)) + (velocity.Y * t);
    velocity.Y = -y;
    Move(new Vector2(velocity.X * dt, velocity.Y));
    velocity.Y += gravity * dt;
}
else
{
    velocity.Y += gravity * dt * 0.5f;
    Move(velocity * dt);
    velocity.Y += gravity * dt * 0.5f;
}
```

This might change depending on which direction is up and down for you, but this is the general gist of it and this gives me the same jump height for all frame rates.

BTW I'm using continuous collision detection, so there is no fear of tunneling or other weird side effects from low frame rates.